# How to handle expiration of refresh token

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

Hi I'm fiddling around Identity server 4. I went through some vids on plural sight and the instructor went through some code on how to refresh my access token using the refresh token.

My question is what happens when the refresh token expires? I tried to see what will happen by setting `AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime=15` but I just get an error when the time elapses i.e. when I try to get data from the resource server. I would expect a redirect to the login page

What is the correct way to handle an expired refresh token? If the correct way is to force the user to login then please provide the code to do this as ids4 does not do this by default.  I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc2",
    ClientName = "MVC Client2",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5001/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5001/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api1"
    },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    RequireConsent = false,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 15,
    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 15,
    IdentityTokenLifetime = 15
}
```

Comment: It is not Identity Server’s concern to handle refresh token. It is up to each client to handle the 401 expired response from resource server and then exchange refresh token for a new access token. Also, I don’t think refresh token is used in OpenId flows where user is involved, only in machine to machine flows such as client credentials. Exception is hybrid flows.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Client credentials is one flow that does not support the refresh token. It doesn't have to as it knows the credentials. For supported flows: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html#refresh-tokens

Answer (score 0):

The *scope* of the refresh token is *offline_access*. This means that the client can request access tokens *on behalf of the user* without having to interact with the user.

Depending on the flow, when the user logs in, the client will receive three tokens: the access token, the identity token and the refresh token.

Being an automated (offline) process, there is no login page. There is no active user, so the return is simply Unauthorized. Meaning that *once expired the user has to login again to start the proces again*.

It is possible that the user can still access the website (using the cookies) while the api is now unaccessable. You can simulate this with the [hybrid flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html) [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess).

Using the configuration of IdentityServer you have several options. You can choose sliding expiration, meaning that the refresh token 'never expires'. And you can set it to one time only use.

I believe that by default the token is set to one time use only, which will trigger IdentityServer to add a new refresh token each time a new access token is requested. Setting the fixed expiration will make sure that the user must login every now and then.

In terms of lifetime:

`access token < refresh token <= AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime`.

Just make sure the refresh token doesn't expire and isn't lost.

If you have a scenario where the refresh token was lost or expired, then logout the user. Go to a secured page which will redirect the user to the login page.

This depends on your configuration, but you could do something like this to logout the user:

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
return LocalRedirect($"/secured");
```

In that case the user may not have to login as the user can still be active because of the SSO cookie.

If you want a full logout (all websites):

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
```

Comment: For some reason await HttpContext.SignOutAsync does not result in a logout. I have to redirect to the logout action to logout.